# Removing a number from a listed created by given numbers

Tags: java, bluej

so here's the details. 
I'm coding using java - BlueJ, and currently have a main class Auction, and a few other classes: Lot, Person, Bid

The purpose of the program is to enter items into the auction, along with their prices, where the information will be stored according to whether it's price, person, or item name/description.

This is the code for my getLot method - user inputs lot number, and it shows info for the lot, which I assume should also be the starting point for the removeLot method since it should still check if the lot number given is valid first.

I'm trying to figure out how to add a removeLot method so that I can remove an item from the lot by typing in its lot number.

This is the code I have for that section.

```
public Lot removeLot(int number)
 {
    if((number >= 1) && (number < nextLotNumber)) {
        // The number seems to be reasonable.
        Lot selectedLot = lots.get(number - 1);
        // Include a confidence check to be sure we have the
        // right lot.
        if(selectedLot.getNumber() != number) {
            System.out.println("Internal error: Lot number " +
                selectedLot.getNumber() +
                " was returned instead of " +
                number);
            // Don't return an invalid lot.
            selectedLot = null;
        }
        **else {
        Lot.removeIf(selectedLot.getNumber() = number);**
        }
        return selectedLot;
```

The else block with the "**" is what I added, wanting to remove the given number. But it's clearly wrong, and I'm not sure what to do.

Answer (score 0):

If the datatype of `lots` variable is `List` than you can try below code

```
public Lot removeLot(int number)
 {
    Lot selectedLot=null;
    if((number >= 1) && (number < nextLotNumber)) {
        // The number seems to be reasonable.
        selectedLot = lots.get(number - 1);
        // Include a confidence check to be sure we have the
        // right lot.
        if(selectedLot.getNumber() != number) {
            System.out.println("Internal error: Lot number " +
                selectedLot.getNumber() +
                " was returned instead of " +
                number);
            // Don't return an invalid lot.
            selectedLot=null;
        }
        else {

            if(selectedLot.getNumber() = number)
                {
                    lots.remove(number-1);
                }

        }
        return selectedLot;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Lot.removeIf(selectedLot.getNumber() = number) is not correct 
you can try:

```
} else if(selectedLot.getNumber() == number) {
   Lot.removeIf(selectedLot.getNumber());
}
```